# Htaccess redirect issue with html entities

Tags: .htaccess

any idea why this line doesnt work

redirect /pages/Contact%7B47%7DCustomer-Service.html /pages/Contact-Customer-Service.html

all the other redirect's in the htaccess file, there is a problem with this specific line of code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have working redirects with HTML entities on other lines? Are you sure, that you can use them in redirects? AFAIK they should be avoided in filenames or URLs.

This is just a guess, but your first entity seems to have four characters asaid percent sign (%7B47), while second one only two (%7D). I'm not sure, but shouldn't entities be always of the same lenght?